# xgboost error with multi classification question

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I got an error when running xgboost multi-classification, I set my label y as numeric, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```py
xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(data=data.matrix(trainX), label=trainY)
xgb_test = xgb.DMatrix(data=data.matrix(testX), label=testY)
watchlist = list(train=xgb_train, test=xgb_test)

xgmodel = xgb.train(data=xgb_train, 
                    objective = "multi:softmax",
                    num_class = 7,
                    max.depth=4, 
                    nrounds=6, 
                    eta = 0.3,
                    gamma = 0,
                    min_child_weight = 1,
                    verbose=1, 
                    watchlist=watchlist, 
                    eval_metric='mae')
```

```py
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  [13:48:41] amalgamation/../src/objective/multiclass_obj.cu:123: SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class).
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   xgboost.so                          0x000000013a6a5ff4 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
  [bt] (1) 2   xgboost.so                          0x000000013a7d6efd xgboost::obj::SoftmaxMultiClassObj::GetGradient(xgboost::HostDeviceVector<float> const&, xgboost::MetaInfo const&, int, xgboost::HostDeviceVector<xgboost::detail::GradientPairInternal<float> >*) + 1069
  [bt] (2) 3   xgboost.so                          0x000000013a77c514 xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int, std::__1::shared_ptr<xgboost::DMatrix>) + 788
  [bt] (3) 4   xgboost.so                          0x000000013a73ff2c XGBoosterUpdateOneIter + 140
  [bt] (4) 5   xgboost.so                          0x000000013a6a28c3 XGBoosterUpdateOneIter_R + 67
  [bt] (5) 6   libR.dylib                          0x000000010e50da82 R_doDotCall + 1458
  [bt] (6) 7   libR.dyli
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer.

My label contains 7 classes starting from 3 to 9. xgboost accepts class label starting from 0, so I subtract all column, and the model run successfully.